# PHP return value if username exists

Tags: php, mysql

The problem I am having is that it always returns true no matter if the username passed in is valid or not.

```
$data = array($_POST["username"]);
$db = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=Example;charset=utf8', 'Example', 'Example');
$stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM Table WHERE username=?");
$num_rows = $stmt->execute($data);

if($num_rows>0){
    echo "true";
}
else{
    echo "false";
}
```

Comment: Very very very much chance in getting injected

Comment: No, the query contains `WHERE username=?`, which takes care of injection issues.

Comment: have u tried `echo $num_rows` before `if` statement to check the value???

Comment: Are you actually going to use the results?

Comment: I return the string to java and convert it into a boolean and check the result

Comment: In that case a `SELECT COUNT(*)` will suffice.

Answer (score 1):

`$stmt->execute($data)` returns `TRUE` on success.

If you want to get the number of rows returned, you need to use `fetchAll` after the `execute`

Answer (score 0):

**USE SQL FUNCTIONS**

`SELECT COUNT(*) as uCount FROM Table WHERE username=? // you can change * to id, for example.`

then check `if($data['uCount'] > 0)`

Answer (score 0):

You can change your SQL statement a little bit and capture either true or false in return as query result.

```
SELECT count(username) > 0 as user_exists FROM Table WHERE username=?
```

Read the query result to find if it is `true` or `false`.

Answer (score 0):

[`PDOStatement::execute()`](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.execute.php) returns a boolean to indicate success; if you're using exception error handling it will always return `true` or throw an exception (recommended by yours truly).

You can fetch the results (assuming there's only one) like this:

```
if (($data = current($stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) !== false) {
    echo "yay";
    // do stuff with $data
} else {
    echo "sorry dude";
}
```

The use of [`current()`](http://php.net/current) returns the first element of the returned result set or `false` if there was none.

**Update**

If you only need to return `true` or `false`, it's better to do just this:

```
$stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Table WHERE username=?");
if ($stmt->execute($data) && current($stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_COLUMN))) {
    echo 'true';
} else {
    echo 'false';
}
```

Answer (score -1):

try this

```
$num_rows = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_NUM);
```